# How to Match & Replace a JSON Response Body for any specific value in Burpsuite

Tags: regex, burp

JSON Response Body:-

```
{
 "field1":value1,
 "field2":value2,
 "field3":value3,
 "field4":value4,
 "field5":value5
}
```

I need to replace specific value of field3 in above JSON response to some other value e.g. valueX

Tried Burpsuite > Proxy > Options > Match and Replace

Enabled: True

Item: Response Body

Match: `^"field3":value3$`

Replace: `"field3":valueX"`

Type: Regex

Expected JSON

```
{ 
"field1":value1, 
"field2":value2, 
"field3":valueX, 
"field4":value4, 
"field5":value5
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What @Toto wants to say is that you should use a JSON parser to get an object you can manipulate and then turn it back into a JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't exactly match the line field3 line. For example, you have a leading space on that line, so ^" will not match.

I recommend you simplify the expression a little:

```
Match: "field3":value3
Replace: "field3":valueX
```